# djangoに関する質問

Tags: django

djangoに関して質問なのですが、以下コードはmessagesに格納されたデータをcontentsに移すという意味が含まれていますでしょうか？views.pyに記載しております。HTMLにて{% for item in contents %}の記載があったのでそうなのではと考えております。

params = {
'login_user':request.user,
'contents':messages,
'check_form':checkform,
'search_form':searchform,
}